# An If statement within an If statement

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

I'm checking to see if a check box has been checked on a search form. If that box has been checked, the value it outputs will be "No".

So if the value is "No", then I want to use an If statement to echo some PHP. The problem is, the PHP that I want to echo is an actual If statement itself.

Here's my code right now:

```
$showoutofstock = $_SESSION['showoutofstock']; 
if ( $showoutofstock == "No" ) {
} 
if($_product->isSaleable()): {
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really "echo some PHP".  PHP is processed on the server-side, and the result is usually HTML that the browser client reads and displays.

It's not clear what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Can you clarify a bit?

This might help though -- it's simply showing how to nest if statements, which may be all that you're asking for:

```
<?php
$showoutofstock = $_SESSION['showoutofstock']; 
if ( $showoutofstock == "No" ) {
    if($_product->isSaleable()) {
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Hey dk, thank you for your answer and my apologies for being unclear. Since I'm doing this within Magento this has to do with displaying search results which show products. If a customer checks the box 'Hide Out of Stock products', that value is 'No'. This is where the if statements come in. I'm trying to insert this line of code 'if($_product->isSaleable())' only IF that 'showoutofstock' value has been set to 'No'. I feel like I'm over complicating this... I'm just not sure how to proceed.

Comment: dk, the code doesn't seem to be working for me. But I tried swapping this line: "if($_product->isSaleable()) {" with "echo "hi"; {" and it worked. Not sure what to do

Comment: @rocky Are you sure `$_SESSION['showoutofstock']` is supposed to be `"No"`?  Now that you understand how to nest `if`s, you need to do some plain old debugging at this point.

Comment: dk, I figured it out. I was doing this within a foreach loop and I had to move those 2 closing brackets from your code to the end of the foreach loop. Thank you so much for the help man.

Comment: dk, if you're still around... I realize that I now need to add an ifelse statement to this code, in case the customer decides they do want to show Out of Stock products, which would mean the box is unchecked, giving it a value of "1". This is what I have so far, it doesn't seem to be working - http://pastie.org/2603682 (By the way, I changed from "No" and "Yes" to "0" and "1".)

Comment: @rocky You now need to move one of the `}` closing brackets up prior to your `elseif` because the `elseif` is currently applying to the inner `if` instead of the outer one that you want it to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3877/discussion-between-rocky-and-dkamins)

Answer (score 2):

you are closing your if before writing another if inside it

```
<?php
    $showoutofstock = $_SESSION['showoutofstock']; 
    if ( $showoutofstock == "No" ) { //main if clause start
        if($_product->isSaleable()) {//if clause inside main if start
        } //inner if clause ends here
    }//outer if clause ends here
?>
```

try it like this and yes you can check for the value of check box and can code accordingly inside that if clause

Comment: Astha, thank you for the answer... your //comments helped me get this working. Upvote sent!